# No setter methods in interface

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

I've a concrete class A that implements an interface B.

```
B ref = new A();
```

Code :

```
public interface B{
  public abstract String[] getWords();
}

public class A implements B {
  private String[] words = new String[] {};
  public void setWords(String[] words){
    this.words = words;
  }
  public String[] getWords(){
    return this.words;
  }
 }
```

In the interface B, I've only getter method but no setter method though the class A has it.

So when I do this : `B ref = new A();`, will this code work and how will I set words?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to cast back to the original type if the interface does expose it

```
if (ref instanceof A)
   ((A) ref).setWords(words);
else
   // something else.
```

A better solution is to add the method to the interface.

Answer (score 5):

You won't be able to call `setWords` on ref if it is defined as `B ref = ...`.

This is one of the cases where you need to use the exact type when declaring the variable (or use a cast):

```
A ref = new A();
```

Alternatively:

- you could create an interface C that extends B and contains both methods and have A implement C.
- you could provide a constructor in A that takes a `String[] words` argument to initialise your `words` field, and not provide a setter at all.

I would personally favour the latter option:

```
public class A implements B {

    private final String[] words;

    public A(String[] words) {
        this.words = words;
    }

    public String[] getWords() {
        return this.words;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks all for the replies.

Answer (score 5):

> So when I do this : B ref = new A();, will this code work...

Yes, it will.

> ...and how will I set words?

You won't be able to unless you:

1. make `A`'s constructor take the list of words; or
2. add `setWords()` to `B`; or
3. keep a reference of type `A` to your object; or
4. downcast `ref` to `A`.

Of these, I would go with one of options 1-3. The last option is only included for completeness.

Answer (score 3):

```
B ref = new A();//1
ref.setWords(whatever);//2
```

The above code wouldn't compile as `setWords()` is not defined in your `interface B`, you'd get a compiler error on line 2.

as other have already expressed in their answers. you got 2 options as work arounds

- Create object as A ref = A();
- Downcast the ref to A type  like ((A)ref).setWords(watever);

Answer (score 0):

> So when I do this : B ref = new A();, will this code work

Yes

> and how will I set words?

You cannot. You need to have setter method in your interface.

Between you don't need to define method as abstract. It is by default abstract.